# Name of this OSX component

Tags: macos, cocoa

I would like to use a component like this one, which basically is a table with a plus/minus button in the bottom left corner, allowing to add/remove a line.

[Unknown component in Xcode http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/556519component.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/556519component.png)

It is used in several places in Xcode, for example in the "Link Frameworks and Libraries" section in the project editor.

Is it a default component that can be found in Interface Builder (it doesn't seem like, I couldn't find it), or do I have to do it by hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a collection of NSView subclasses -- not a single pre-cooked NSView subclass.

So you have something like an NSTableView and some buttons for the primary visible components. If you find it a common need, you could create your own reusable implementation.

Comment: Aw okay. I just thought maybe it was a system component since it's used in many places (like in the Finder). Anyway, thanks for the answer!